# Creating a child object using a parent object

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let say I have these classes:

```
Class A {};
Class B : A {} ;
```

and a function that return an `A`:

```
 public A read_an_A();
```

since `B` is a child of `A`, I'd like to be able to read it's `A` properties in the following sense:

```
B b = new B ( read_an_A() );
```

(that assuming use of default copy constructor)

or maybe something like this:

```
B b = (B) read_an_A ();
```

All of the above are obviously broken, what is the right way to achieve that?

Comment: I don't understand the situation, do you know for sure that the A returned is B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is to add a constructor of B that takes A, and harvests the relevant parts from it:

```
public B(A a) {
    this.x = a.x;
    this.y = a.y;
}
```

Your B class is in the best position to know what to take, so this approach is reasonably clean, too. It lets you write

```
B b = new B(read_an_A());
```

like you suggested in your question. Of course B would very likely need other constructors, too.

Comment: OK. So I guess I expected it to be done automatically, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know if the A retuned is B - you need to make sure or you will get a runtime exception

```
var a = read_an_A();
if (a is B) 
{
    var b = (B)a;
    ....
}
```

Comment: well, it's never the issue. I actually *now* it's always an `A`. I was just hopping there's an elegant way. like some a default partial copy constructor.

Comment: So that's not the right way of doing that, you don't inherit just to use some data, an inheritance is a "is" relationship, it means B is a type of A (Dog is a type of Animal, Truck is a type of Car, etc), in your situation B use A, B is not A